# Get the value of an appended input field using post method

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

So i have these dynamic fields that generates input fields. When i tried to get the value, post method didnt work. Only the fields that generated using append were not working.

Here's my code.

Javascript

```
 $('#form_save').submit(function(e){
    var form = $(this);
    var form_data = new FormData(form[0]);
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: base_url+'Prods/save_product',
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,   
        cache: false,      
        processData:false,
        ..................... and so on.
```

then i tried to fetech using `$this->input->post('appended_field')`, its not working.

HTML

```
<form id="form_save" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <div class="col-md-6 nostocksdiv" id="nostocksdiv2">

   </div>
</form>
```

append js function

```
$('#nostocksdiv2').append("<div class='form-group divnostock' id='div_no_of_stocks_0'><label>Available quantity(Main Branch)</label><input type='number' class='form-control' name='f_no_of_stocks_0' id='f_no_of_stocks_0' placeholder='Number of stocks' value='0'></div>");
```

what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: where did you append it in form tag or outside of form tag? show us your HTML code and js code

Comment: Inside form tag bro @M.Hemant

Comment: @M.Hemant I edited my question bro

Comment: your input tag name is f_no_of_stocks_0 and your post argument is appended_field.